# Syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) - Somente no Servidor Remoto

Tags: php, zend, zend-framework-3

Tenho uma plataforma que desenvolvi usando Zend Framework 3.0.

Essa plataforma funciona no local mas quando a migrei para o servidor, ela atira múltiplos erros com esta *syntax*:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/gowebsales/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/FormElementManager/FormElementManagerV3Polyfill.php on line 37

A minha plataforma esta a correr PHP na versão 5.6. O servidor esta a correr 5.4.

Que alterações preciso de fazer para resolver este problema?

Comment: Se as versões do PHP são diferentes, você já tem um forte candidato a causador do problema, não é?

Comment: Eu sei que as versões de php são quem esta a causar o erro.. Eu queria era saber como e o que que eu tenho de alterar para plataforma funcionar.

Comment: Não é só atualizar o PHP do servidor?

Comment: Sim, mas não era sensato mudar a versao do servidor, que esta hospedar multiplos websites, so para a minha plataforma funcionar

Comment: Pois é. Você deveria ter pensado nisso antes então. PHP tem essas incompatibilidades entre versões mesmo, não tem o que fazer. Se você sabia que a aplicação iria rodar num servidor com 5.4 deveria ter desenvolvido usando o 5.4. _A priori_ você só tem duas opções: **1)** Fazer sua aplicação rodar na versão correta do PHP (independentemente de como isso será feito); e **2)** Adaptar sua aplicação para rodar na versão 5.4 do PHP.

Comment: Falei com o patrão da empresa em que estou atualmente a trabalhar. A empresa ira criar um alojamento na versão 5.6, que vai solucionar o problema.
Transforme em resposta para que possa encerrar a pergunta e, obrigado pela ajuda ! :)

Comment: Na documentação do framework consta: [Zend Framework 3 requires PHP 5.6](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é um problema na resolução de nomes de classes. A causa disso você mesmo disse na pergunta: as versões do PHP são diferentes no desenvolvimento e no servidor de publicação.

*A priori* você só tem duas opções: **1**) Fazer sua aplicação rodar na versão correta do PHP - independentemente de como isso será feito; e **2**) Adaptar sua aplicação para rodar na versão 5.4 do PHP.